# Developing a python Scraper that opens all links in multiple tabs using Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to develop a scraper using python that will open links within a webpage in multiple tabs in Chrome.

The code I have managed to put together is

```
import urllib2
from datetime import timedelta, date
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

i = driver.get("https://investmentinsightindia.wordpress.com/")

driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(',').click()
driver.get("chrome://newtab/")
```

I have figured out that most individual posts on that site have a ',' (in the date) so I have tried to click on the link that has a , in it's text.

I do realise to make it work on multiple sites, I would eventually need to use something more generic to a link like an href reference from Xpath, I don't know how to do that.

How can I configure it -
1. Opens the homepage (url)
2. Opens the first available link in a new tab
3. Leaves the tab open
4. Opens the second available link in a new tab.....and so on

Comment: can you clear one thing . Do you want to click `Posted on May 17, 2013` this kind of link ? as comma `,` is in date

Comment: I want to click on every new post in the page. Clicking on the datestamp was just a method I thought will cover. Ideally I'd like to click on all the posts present in the webpage

Comment: can you see my updated answer and try in python . let me know incase any issue. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can find elements that are links by finding the `'a'` elements and then looping over them and clicking one by one.

You can achieve that something like this :

```
for elem in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a') : 
    elem.click()
    driver.get("chrome://newtab/")
```

This will open all the urls in the new tab one-by-one.

Comment: I tried it, getting -selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Is there anything specific that '//a' I can use to describe the link better?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement to open specific post links which contains `,` in dates e.g. `Posted on May 17, 2013` Then get all same kind of element in a list using following xpath :

```
//a/span[contains(text(),',')]
```

OR

can use below xpath to get all post links

```
//h2/a
```

and iterate through the for loop. Below is sample Java example to do the same Please implement as per python syntax

```
 List <WebElement> allElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a/span[contains(text(),',')]/parent::*")); // will get all anchor tag which having , and store in a list

 System.out.println(allElement.size());
 for(WebElement element:allElement)
 {
    System.out.println(element.getAttribute("href"));
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(element.getAttribute("href"));
 }
```